# statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots plot problem (jupyter)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, statsmodels

I have an interesting problem. There is no error in code but, it plots different from what i wrote.

```
import statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots as sgt
sgt.plot_acf(df_model.ISLEM, lags=40, zero=False)
sgt.plot_pacf(df_model.ISLEM, lags=40, zero=False, method=('ols'))
```

It gives this (3 graphic - 2 of them are partial autocorrelation). It should give 2 graphic;

[image]

How can avoid this problem?

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the problem? What is your expected output? Also provide a [mcve] we cannot reproduce your issue at the moment.

Comment: @jlandercy sorry, it should give total 2 graphic but there is 2 of the partial graphic

Comment: Try to define the matplotlib suplot array explicitly using `fig, axarr = plt.subplots(1,2)` and then `sgt.plot_acf(..., ax=axarr[0][1])` or similar. That's generally good practice because it gives you better control over where the subplots end up.

Comment: This is a known [issue](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1265); to fix it, assign a variable to last line so IPython doesn't output its return value e.g. change last line to `_ = sgt.plot_pacf(df_model.ISLEM, lags=40, zero=False, method=('ols'))
`.

Comment: Thank you @MustafaAydın it solved my problem :)